# check if value exists in all indexes of array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

So i have an array (size 5) of characters, each index containing a character, and i'm getting user input of a character to search for in the array. But i'm not sure how to check if `char cInput` is present in all indexes of the array.

```
char cLetters[5] = {'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'};
char cInput;
cout << "Enter a character to search for: ";
cin >> cInput;
```

I shouldn't have to do this right?

```
if(cInput == cLetters[0] && cInput == cLetters[1] && cInput == cLetters[2] 
&& cInput == cLetters[3] && cInput == cLetters[4])
          return true;
```

Especially if the size of the array was 200, i wouldn't write that condition 200 times.

Any ideas?

Comment: your question is tagged for-loop. how about that for an idea?

Comment: I've been brain farting all day. My apologies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the C++11 algorithm in `<algorithm>`, [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Example code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char x[] = { 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' };
    if(std::all_of(std::begin(x), std::end(x), [](char c) { return c == 'b'; })) {
        std::cout << "all are b!";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, It's actually quite incredible how many useful algorithms and utilities were added to C++11 that seem to go unknown. `std::to_string` and `std::stoi` took me ages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for a way to do this with bools and came up with this:

```
auto is_true = std::bind(std::equal_to<bool>(), std::placeholders::_1, true);
return std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), is_true)
```

With a const char it would look like so:

```
auto is_b = std::bind(std::equal_to<char>(), std::placeholders::_1, 'b');
return std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), is_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input char is not present in all indices if it is absent in either one of those. Loop through the array to see that

```
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i){
    if (cInput != cLetters[i])
        return 0;
}
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use a C++11 range-based for loop to simplify the code a little:

```
for (auto ch : cLetters)
    if (ch != cInput)
        return false;
return true;
```