# C++11 equivalent to Python's all() function

Tags: python, c++11, iterable, built-in

Is there an equivalent function to Python's [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in function?

In other words: Does a C++11 function exist that returns `true` when all of the elements of an iterable meet a certain condition and `false` otherwise?

Comment: how strange. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590733/check-if-value-exists-in-all-indexes-of-array) is the closest thing to a dupe I could find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `std::all_of` in the `<algorithm>` header. You can pass a custom predicate that evaluates to true or false on each element.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for doing the same thing with template parameter pack (like `template <bool... values>`) you can use fold expression: `(values && ...)`, but only since C++17. Documentation of this feature is here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold