# Logical operation between all elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays, operators, bitwise-operators

I want to compare all items in my array using a boolean operator in the most efficient way. Currently, I have something like this :

```
bool myFunction(int i) 
{

    bool *myArray = {true, true, false, false, true};
    //suppose we know that i = 5 and that i is the length of the array...
    return myArray[0] && myArray[1] && myArray[2] && myArray[3] && myArray[4];
}
```

Since the size of the array is not fixed, the value of 'i' can change and my return statement would no longer be working, so I would have to implement something like this

```
bool myFunction(int i) 
{
    bool *myArray = //some other array of bools
    //should work with any value of i
    bool result = myArray[0];
    for (int a = 1; a < i; ++a)
    {
        result &= myArray[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this other than making a for loop and going through each elements and comparing the value of the next item in list with the stored result from the previous two items. Like some bitwise operators that would make this easy or something, anything to take out the loop.

Comment: First things first: there are no VLAs in standard C++.

Comment: Right my bad haha, still new to this language :S

Comment: Here are some good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590733/check-if-value-exists-in-all-indexes-of-array

Comment: You can use a std::vector for this sort of thing. But what is it you want to do on all elements? If that's what you want there are algos that work on the vector.

Comment: I just want to do an 'AND' operation on all the items within the array, or an 'OR' operation. Wanted to know if there was a more effective method than looping through the array,

Comment: I think NO_NAME's link does what I want it to do, I'll try it out :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) (replace`std::begin(myArray) + i` with `std::end(myArray)` if you want to check entire array and not first `i` elements):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
bool myFunction(int i)
{
    std::vector<bool> myArray = { true, true, false, false, true };
    return std::all_of(std::begin(myArray), std::begin(myArray) + i, [](bool elem) { return elem; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to know that `&=` is not a logical operator; it is the "bitwise and" operator.  As long as you only use it on booleans, I guess it will work ok; but C won't stop a value other than 1 or 0 from slipping into the array, so you should probably not make that assumption.  Semantically if you're doing a logical or you want `&&` instead of `&`.

That said, you can certainly use short-circuiting to refine what you're doing.  Once you've found a single 0 (false), nothing from then on is going to make your aggregate go back to 1 (true), so you might as well stop.

```
for (int a = 1; result && a < i; ++a)
{
    result &= myArray[i];
}
```

Other than that, there's not much you can improve.  Not sure why you're averse to a loop, but if you want to combine an unknown number of values you're going to have to iterate.  You might find (or write) some utility function to do it, but it'll be using a loop internally anyway.  (Unless it tries to leverage a vector processor that natively does what you want, maybe... but that would be rather pointless and, if you truly don't have a limit on number of values, will *still* involve a loop.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), it has a member fuction `any()` that will return `true` if any bits in this bitset are set. And `none()` will return `true` if no bits are set.

But the implementation of [`any()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp) is:

```
template <typename Block, typename Allocator>
bool dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>::any() const
{
    for (size_type i = 0; i < num_blocks(); ++i)
        if (m_bits[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

So you have inside a for loop!

But if you are searching for something like parallel computing, you may want to use [*arrayfire*](http://arrayfire.org/docs/index.htm):
For example it has an [algorithm](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__reduce__func__all__true.htm)     that do it.

```
template<typename T >
T af::allTrue(  const array &   in  )   
//C++ Interface for checking if all values in an array are true.
```

Comment: I suppose that depends on how you define the problem.  The question specifies that the data structure is an array of bools, so this assumes that can be changed.  And if the goal is to avoid the loop, all this does is hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the loop as soon as you encounter `false`:

```
for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
{
    if (!myArray[i])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

---

If you're allowed to change the last value in the array, then here's a trick for optimizing it:

- If the last value in the array is `false`, then return `false`
- Write `false` into the last entry in the array
- Iterate the array until you encounter `false`
- Write `true` into the last entry in the array
- If you stopped **before** the last entry, then return `false`
- Return `true`

The code:

```
int a;
if (!myArray[i-1])
    return false;
myArray[i-1] = false;
for (a = 0; a < i; a++)
{
    if (!myArray[i])
        break;
}
myArray[i-1] = true;
return a != i-1;
```

This yields one branch per iteration instead of two branches per iteration.

---

If you're allowed to allocate `i+1` entries, then you can get rid of the "last entry swapping" part:

```
int a;
myArray[i] = false;
for (a = 0; myArray[i]; i++);
return a != i;
```

You can also get rid of the additional arithmetic embedded in `myArray[i]`:

```
bool *arrayPtr;
myArray[i] = false;
for (arrayPtr = myArray; *arrayPtr; arrayPtr++);
return arrayPtr != myArray+i;
```

If the compiler doesn't already apply it, then this function will do so for sure. On the other hand, it might make it harder on the optimizer to unroll the loop, so you will have to verify that in the generated assembly code...

Answer (score 0):

I would change the condition of your for-loop so you won't continue if you encounter a false value and use an iterator instead of an index.

```
bool myFunction(int i) {
    bool myArray[i] = //some other array of bools
    //should workwith any value of i

    bool result;
    bool * a;
    for (a = myArray, result = *a; a < myArray+i && result; result=*(++i)) {}
    //no need to use the AND operator since we stop if we meet one false

    return result;
}
```

Or if you really prefer with index:

```
bool myFunction(int i) {
    bool myArray[i] = //some other array of bools
    //should workwith any value of i

    bool result;
    unsigned int a;
    for (a = 0, result = myArray[a]; a < i && result; result=myArray[++i]) {}
    //no need to use the AND operator since we stop if we meet one false

    return result;
}
```

Maybe I'm wrong, but I wouldn't use the bitwise AND assignment (&=) if it's not on bit range operation, it's not really relevant on the bool type though.